# How to remove content based on regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to replace/delete the content from the text file based on the regx. I wonder if I can do this in notepad++.

Below is the file content and I need to remove everything after `*soa_` in each line of the file.

```
_modifycustomerdetails!1.0*soa_9d8e3a58-3d01-40e7-aab7-10c743c78516
_modifycustomerdetails!1.0*soa_8e2301e5-6b8e-496c-bc5d-38234c017cb8
```

How can I do update the content?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you edit your question and include this information? By the way, take a look at the [ask] page to improve the chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\*.*\b or  \*.*\ // both cases worked by me
```

as pattern in the FindWhat in Replace and

```
empty space in
```

ReplaceWith